# Arguments are located on different GPUs when using nn.DataParallel(model)

Tags: python, pytorch, multi-gpu

Torch 0.4.1

Python 2.7.12

I was adapting [NMP QC code](https://github.com/priba/nmp_qc) [(with some compatibility issues ironed out)](https://github.com/priba/nmp_qc/pull/5/commits/b59efc524827d62ec46f8c85c19849c30fadb652) to use multiple GPUs since my GPU couldn't handle the workload (crashed after running out of VRAM)

I'm new to pytorch, but I found [a tutorial on using nn.DataParallel(model)](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/data_parallel_tutorial.html) to implement multi-gpu use

I [modified main.py to use nn.DataParallel(model).](https://pastebin.com/w5fvQ3VS) Areas I changed have "#NEW" stuck to them.

The code runs fine even in multi-gpu mode if running on a single GPU, but gets a "arguments are located on different GPUs" error when running on 2 or more GPU

```
libibverbs: Warning: couldn't open config directory '/etc/libibverbs.d'.
libibverbs: Warning: no userspace device-specific driver found for /sys/class/infiniband_verbs/uverbs3
libibverbs: Warning: no userspace device-specific driver found for /sys/class/infiniband_verbs/uverbs2
libibverbs: Warning: no userspace device-specific driver found for /sys/class/infiniband_verbs/uverbs1
libibverbs: Warning: no userspace device-specific driver found for /sys/class/infiniband_verbs/uverbs0
Unexpected end of /proc/mounts line `overlay / overlay rw,relatime,lowerdir=/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/QKSBQ5PAFDDC3OMBEELQQETALQ:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/WWYI3IDQPNXGON7AHODBPSTVXL:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/Q54I2HYS4TKH4LDJKBTVTGWWO6:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/IUV2LFPNMPOS3MREOTT52TKL54:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/DB5GBUCI3DCBPX6TJG3O337YVB:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/DNYKXCZJH5FMFNJLNGYJJ2ITPI:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/7DZCTDVNSTPJISGW65UG7U3F75:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/VOEQO652VS63NLDLZZ4TCIJLO6:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/l/4SI6ZCRUIORG5'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 332, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 190, in main
    train(train_loader, model, criterion, optimizer, epoch, evaluation, logger)
  File "main.py", line 251, in train
    output = model(g, h, e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 477, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/parallel/data_parallel.py", line 123, in forward
    outputs = self.parallel_apply(replicas, inputs, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/parallel/data_parallel.py", line 133, in parallel_apply
    return parallel_apply(replicas, inputs, kwargs, self.device_ids[:len(replicas)])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/parallel/parallel_apply.py", line 77, in parallel_apply
    raise output
RuntimeError: arguments are located on different GPUs at /pytorch/aten/src/THC/generic/THCTensorMathBlas.cu:236
```

Since I was sending the inputs one at a time instead of at once like in the tutorial, I checked by using .get_device(), which confirmed all 4 arguments being sent (g, h, e, target) were on the same device (device 0)

Comment: Could you show us the MPNN code? I had a similar issue once, which was related to the wrong usage of net parameters in the nn's code.

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm using the version sitting on pull request
https://github.com/priba/nmp_qc/blob/b59efc524827d62ec46f8c85c19849c30fadb652/models/MPNN.py
edited the main post just now

Comment: Did you check if not only `g, h, e` and `target` were moved to GPU, but also every net-parameter and every value used for computation in forward is located on the right GPU?

Comment: I haven't checked since I thought that would be handled by model.to(device). I haven't touched anything besides main.py. 
Looking at MPNN.forward(), it looks like it's not taking any inputs besides [g, h, e], although it is using self.m, self.u, and self.r, none of which are explicitly moved using to(device)

Comment: `model.to(device)` should be enough, if every value used is defined as a parameter / part of a module, that seems to be done correctly. For debugging I would check the devices of all used variables, just to be sure everything was moved right, but I do not have multiple GPUs available to reproduce this problem.

Comment: Sorry, but we decided to not pursue this issue. Should I delete this post, or leave it up?